# Creating an AVPlayerLayer causes simulator to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, avplayer, simulator

I've got a class that returns an AVPlayer and AVSynchronisedLayer in a callback. When I use the AVPlayer to initialise an AVPlayerLayer, I get a crash (only happens in the simulator). The code looks like this:

```
  self.projectPlayer = [[MYMobilePlayer alloc] init];
  [self.projectPlayer setDelegate:self]; 
  [self.projectPlayer returnPlayerForProjectScene:self.projectScene andCallback:^(NSError *error, AVPlayer *player, AVSynchronizedLayer *syncLayer) {


      self.syncLayer = syncLayer;
      AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
      NSLog(@"%@",playerLayer); // Also crashes if I assign to private member variable
      // More code that uses the playerLayer - not needed to illustrate the problem

  }];
```

The objects being returned in the callback are correct, so I don't think I need to show the code that creates and returns them.

The stack trace is shown below (not very helpful).

[image]

Any idea what might be happening here?

Answer (score 0):

`UIKit` code should always be called on the main thread. Your `returnPlayerForProjectScene` callback is happening on some other video processing thread. Dispatching the code in question to the main queue should fix your crash:

```
[self.projectPlayer returnPlayerForProjectScene:self.projectScene andCallback:^(NSError *error, AVPlayer *player, AVSynchronizedLayer *syncLayer) {

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        self.syncLayer = syncLayer;
        AVPlayerLayer *playerLayer = [AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:player];
        NSLog(@"%@",playerLayer); // Also crashes if I assign to private member variable
        // More code that uses the playerLayer - not needed to illustrate the problem

    });
}];
```

Comment: Thank you @Rhythmic Fistman for your answer. I tried it and it doesn't fix it unfortunately. Its not the UI work that is causing the crash however - simply instantiating the AVPlayerLayer is enough.

Comment: ah too bad, does the stack trace change now that you're instantiating `AVPlayerLayer` on the right thread?

Comment: No, unfortunately the stack trace is the same. and its happening on the same thread (com.apple.coremedia.videoprocessor)